# How to get document preview image using SharePoint CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, authorization, office365, csom

I would like to programmatically retrieve thumbnails of documents from SharePoint. What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
document.GetImagePreviewUrl(width, height, clientType);
```

This just returns an empty `ClientResult`. I am not sure what to enter as `clientType` value.

I have also tried to use [this](http://blog.beecomedigital.com/2015/07/27/generate-thumbnail-of-a-document-stored-in-sharepoint-from-its-url/) method programmatically (by using `WebClient` and downloading the file). But that just returns a `403` response.

The possible solutions I see here are the following:

- Figure out what to enter as `clientType` and retrieve the preview url that way.
- Figure out how to tell SharePoint that I am authorized programmatically (using `WebClient` and headers for instance).

I do need some help regarding these two options, I am not sure where to start since both options aren't well documented.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out a way to do it, the `403` error was caused because sharepoint had no idea who I was. After some research and fiddling I found out that the request you send to the preview page contains an authentication cookie. This cookie can be generated by code using this piece of code:

```
// Create an authentication cookie which we can send with the request so sharepoint knows who we are.
var authCookie = credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(new Uri(imageUrl));
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, authCookie);
// Download the image data to a byte array
image = client.DownloadData(imageUrl);
```