# the CSOM call GetImagePreviewUrl returns Object but empty Value

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I am trying to use the CSOM call of GetImagePreviewUrl, but I believe I might not be using it correctly.

While I can code in C# I am not a SharePoint user or administrator so that might be part of my issue here.  I have full access rights to the sites in SharePoint that I am querying and I can call the ClientContext without issue and return a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.  I am using this same code to obtain lists and file information else where in my system.  From this file it shows that I should be able to call the GetImagePreviewUrl and return a preview image.  The call will return me a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest but the Value is always a null (image below).  Here are lines of my code slapped together for brevity.

```
var ctx = new ClientContext("http://mysharepointResource/andSite");
ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += appendBearerToken;     // just adding headers here
ctx.RequestTimeout = Timeout.Infinite;

Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.File file = ctx.Web.GetFileByUrl(value);
ctx.Load(file);
await ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync();

var previewUri = file.GetImagePreviewUri(300,300, "docLibGrid");
```

I am thinking maybe two things might be wrong here, first I might be using the wrong value for the third parameter.  My example code uses the "docLibGrid" string because I got that from an example I saw [here.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/modern-webpage-error-with-getpreview-ashx-when-a-repost-page-is/m-p/269989/highlight/true#M22469)  But maybe this should be like a web pages header content-type value instead.  Should it be a "image/jpeg" value like a preview image might be, or is this supposed to represent the content-type of the original file? I have tried a few different header types and these return me the same NULL values.

My second thought I have is maybe I have something setup wrong on the SharePoint site itself and therefore I am receiving a NULL in the Value field of the returned ClientResult.  Do I need to ask the administrator to open something up or maybe I need to validate that Preview Images exist?  I have been to the SharePoint site and followed a few ways to view the preview images so I do not think it is this.

[image]

I appreciate any help or pointers, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

List item **EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl** property stores image thumbnail url, the following example shows how to get it:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))             
{
    var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(pictureLibraryTitle);
    var item = list.GetItemById(itemId);
    ctx.Load(item, i => i["EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl"]);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine(item["EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl"]);
}
```

Comment: This does give a semi solution to my question form a perspective of wanting to use CSOM in order to get these values.  But if anyone can give me some understanding as to how to use the "GetImagePreviewUri" method and it is parameters I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why not to use the getpreview.ashx. In that case , you only need to call the ashx with complete file path. So in this case you only need to call this with bearer token as GET with complete url of image or a news page image e.g. https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePoint/_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?path=https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePoint/SitePages/xyz.aspx

Comment: The user is not authenticated, this is all going through a backend API endpoint that authenticates and retrieves files including thumbnails, so the getPreview.ASHX handler is not really a great design for this from what I can see, it is awesome for direct calls though.

Comment: the request you send to the preview page contains an authentication cookie. This cookie can be generated by following code:  Create an authentication cookie which we can send with the request so sharepoint knows who we are.
      var authCookie = credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(new Uri(imageUrl));
      client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, authCookie);
      // Download the image data to a byte array
      image = client.DownloadData(imageUrl);

Comment: This may be a duplicate in your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387858/how-to-get-document-preview-image-using-sharepoint-csom

Comment: Nobody bothers answering the question of what the Client Type is over there either, so a duplicate Non-Answer.

Comment: I think your answers can be very relevant, why don't you expand on your answer so others who read this thread can understand what you mean instead of commenting with a few code snippets in the comments, this way it might be clear to others who need help and are not experts.